# gcc makefile error: "No rule to make target ..."

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm trying to use GCC (linux) with a makefile to compile my project.

I get the following error which is can't seem to decipher in this context:

```
"No rule to make target 'vertex.cpp', needed by 'vertex.o'.  Stop."
```

This is the makefile:

```makefile
a.out: vertex.o edge.o elist.o main.o vlist.o enode.o vnode.o
    g++ vertex.o edge.o elist.o main.o vlist.o enode.o vnode.o

main.o: main.cpp main.h
    g++ -c main.cpp

vertex.o: vertex.cpp vertex.h
    g++ -c vertex.cpp

edge.o: edge.cpp edge.h
    g++ -c num.cpp

vlist.o: vlist.cpp vlist.h
    g++ -c vlist.cpp

elist.o: elist.cpp elist.h
    g++ -c elist.cpp

vnode.o: vnode.cpp vnode.h
    g++ -c vnode.cpp

enode.o: enode.cpp enode.h
    g++ -c node.cpp
```

Comment: A typical example you 'make' the source file 'not exist' is by resetting VPATH or SRC variable  by mistake when you have to add to it. I mean usnig `VPATH=` instead of `VPATH+=`. This makes Makefile file can't see the files when the file actually is there.

Answer (score 563, accepted):

That's usually because you don't have a file called `vertex.cpp` available to make. Check that:

- that file exists.
- you're in the right directory when you make.

Other than that, I've not much else to suggest. Perhaps you could give us a directory listing of that directory.

Comment: Yes, Some of my classes don't have .cpp files, so they weren't there- causing the error. Thanks.

Comment: you can also get such an error if there are some header files that you removed but are still in your Makefile

Comment: Also, make sure you save your Makefile after editing it... That is what got me. I did all my edits then forgot to press CTRL+S

Comment: `No rule to make target 'X'` when `X` is simply missing. What a bad wording that will survive the centuries because everybody gets used to it.

Answer (score 102):

In my experience, this error is frequently caused by a **spelling** error.

I got this error today.

> make[1]: *** No rule to make target `maintenaceDialog.cpp', needed by`maintenaceDialog.o'.  Stop.

In my case the error was simply a spelling error.  The word MAINTENANCE was missing it's third N.

Also check the spelling on your filenames.

Comment: The meta _why_, in this case is because of explicitly listing the object/source/header relationships.  If newer tools like _SubCons_ or _CMake_ are not to taste, `gcc -MT`  and gnu make patterns can solve this. See [also](http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html).

Comment: In my case the path was wrong like `../../src/file.c` but actually it was `../../src/folder/file.c`

Answer (score 36):

The more common reason for this message to be printed is because you forgot to include the directory in which the source file resides. As a result, gcc "thinks" this file does not exist.

You can add the directory using the -I argument to gcc.

Comment: The `-I` directive is for ***include*** files and has nothing to do with where files like `vertex.cpp` can be found by `make`.

Answer (score 16):

In my case I had bone-headedly used commas as separators. To use your example I did this:

```
a.out: vertex.o, edge.o, elist.o, main.o, vlist.o, enode.o, vnode.o
    g++ vertex.o edge.o elist.o main.o vlist.o enode.o vnode.o
```

Changing it to the equivalent of

```
a.out: vertex.o edge.o elist.o main.o vlist.o enode.o vnode.o
    g++ vertex.o edge.o elist.o main.o vlist.o enode.o vnode.o
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 14):

Is that it exactly? Remember that Makefile syntax is whitespace aware and requires tabs to indent commands under actions.

Answer (score 14):

In my case it was due to I crated file like `MakeFile` instead it should be `Makefile`.

Answer (score 13):

One of frequent mistakes might be **typo in another file name**.

You example is quite straightforward but what may sometimes confuse are 
messages of `make` itself. Lets consider an example.

My folder contents is:

```
$ ls -1
another_file
index.md
makefile
```

Whereas my `makefile` looks like

```
all: index.html

%.html: %.md wrong_path_to_another_file
    @echo $@ $<
```

Although I do have `index.md` where it should be and there is no mistake in the name of it, the message from `make` will be

```
make: *** No rule to make target `index.html', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

To be honest **the message is confusing**. It just says, that there is no rule. In fact, it means that the rule is wrong, but due to wildcard (pattern) rules `make` cannot determine what exactly caused the issue.

Lets alter `makefile` a little, which is to say replace patterns with explicit rules:

```
index.html: index.md wrong_path_to_another_file
```

And now the message we get will be:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `wrong_path_to_another_file', needed by `index.html'.  Stop.
```

Miracle! The following might be concluded:

- Messages of `make` depends on rules and does not always point to the root of problems
- There might be other problems in your `makefile` different from specified by this message

Now we've come up with the idea of **checking other dependencies in a rule** as well:

```
all: index.html

%.html: %.md another_file
    @echo $@ $<
```

Only this will provide us with the desired result:

```
$ make
index.html index.md
```

Comment: Is there a way to write the makefile with pattern rules - short of listing every target - so that it correctly complains about the file that it's actually missing? In this case wrong_path_to_another_file

Comment: @creanion, I havent check whether wildcard works differently, you may try somthing like
`objects := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))`
`foo : $(objects)`
        `cc -o foo $(objects)`

Answer (score 9):

The problem I found was even sillier than what other folks have mentioned.

Our makefiles get passed lists of things to build. Someone added `TheOtherLibrary` to one of the lists, as shown below.

```
LIBRARYDIRS = src/Library
LIBRARYDIRS = src/TheOtherLibrary
```

They should have done this:

```
LIBRARYDIRS = src/Library
LIBRARYDIRS += src/TheOtherLibrary
```

Had they done it the second way, they would not have wiped out the `Library` build. The plus in `+=` is very important.

Answer (score 7):

In my case it was due to a multi-line rule error in the Makefile. I had something like:

```
OBJS-$(CONFIG_OBJ1)            += file1.o file2.o \
                                  file3.o file4.o \
OBJS-$(CONFIG_OBJ2)            += file5.o 
OBJS-$(CONFIG_OBJ3)            += file6.o
...
```

The backslash at the end of file list in `CONFIG_OBJ1`'s rule caused this error. It should be like:

```
OBJS-$(CONFIG_OBJ1)            += file1.o file2.o \
                                  file3.o file4.o
OBJS-$(CONFIG_OBJ2)            += file5.o
...
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to build John the Ripper "bleeding-jumbo" and get an error like "make: *** No rule to make target 'linux-x86-64'". Try running this command instead: `./configure && make`

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the error message referred to an old filename, which did no longer exist because it was renamed. It turned out that the outdated information did not come from the Makefile, but from files in `.deps` directories.

I ran into this error after copying files from one machine to another. In that process, I assume the timestamps got in an inconsistent state, which confused "make" when running multiple jobs in parallel (similar to [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45118)).

Sequential builds with `make -j 1` were not affected, but it took me a while to realize because I was using an alias (`make -j 8`).

To clean up the state, I removed all `.deps` files and regenerated the Makefile. These are the commands that I used:

```
find | grep '.deps' | xargs rm
find | grep '.deps' | xargs rmdir
autoreconf --install # (optional, but my project is using autotools) 
./configure
```

After that, building worked again.

Answer (score 4):

**In my case, the reason for this error was that a folder name had a space, renaming the folder solved the problem**

---

Example:

```
~/foo bar/mymoduledir
```

renaming the folder `foo bar` to `foo_bar`:

```
~/foo_bar/mymoduledir
```

fixes the problem

Comment: Same here. A folder several levels up had a space in it. I believe it's when the Makefile has a $PWD entry - it injects the true value, but doesn't escape the spaces.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the path is not set in VPATH, after added the error gone.

Answer (score 3):

My case was a missing `$`:

Instead of:

```
(LINK_TARGET): $(OBJS)
```

Should be:

```
$(LINK_TARGET): $(OBJS)
```

Edit:

I had this same problem, but now due to another reason, it was due to an `echo` command inside my `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 2):

Another example of a weird problem and its solution:

This:

```
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${Poco_LIBRARIES}
    ${Poco_Foundation_LIBRARY}
    ${Poco_Net_LIBRARY}
    ${Poco_Util_LIBRARY}
    )
```

gives: `make[3]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/libPocoFoundationd.so', needed by '../hello_poco/bin/mac/HelloPoco'.  Stop.`

But if I remove `Poco_LIBRARIES` it works:

```
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${Poco_Foundation_LIBRARY}
    ${Poco_Net_LIBRARY}
    ${Poco_Util_LIBRARY}
    )
```

I'm using clang8 on Mac and clang 3.9 on Linux
The problem only occurs on Linux but works on Mac!

I forgot to mention: `Poco_LIBRARIES` was wrong - it was not set by cmake/find_package!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple reasons for this error.

One of the reason where i encountered this error is while building for linux and windows.

I have a filename with caps BaseClass.h SubClass.h
Unix maintains has case-sensitive filenaming convention and windows is case-insensitive.

[C++ why people don't use uppercase in name of header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503532/c-why-people-dont-use-uppercase-in-name-of-header-files)

Try compiling clean build using gmake clean if you are using gmake

Some text editors has default settings to ignore case-sensitive filenames. This could also lead to the same error.

[how to add a c++ file in Qt Creator whose name starts with capital letters ? It automatically makes it small letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792511/how-to-add-a-c-file-in-qt-creator-whose-name-starts-with-capital-letters-it)

Answer (score 2):

This message can mean many things clearly.

In my case it was compiling using multiple threads. One thread needed a dependency that another thread hadn't finished making, causing an error.

Not all builds are threadsafe, so consider a slow build with one thread if your build passes other tests such as the ones listed above.

Comment: how to do a slow build ?

Comment: @GuidoG Set your threadcount to 1 (add -j1 to the build flags).

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred for me inside Travis when I forgot to add new files to my git repository. Silly mistake, but I can see it being quite common.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the source and/or old object file(s) were locked (read-only) by a semi-crashed IDE or from a backup cloud service that stopped working properly. Restarting all programs and services that were associated with the folder structure solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue popped out after removing some of the header files and .c files and the project didn't compile.

Running **clean** and then **build** compiled the project

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it was due to me calling the Makefile: MAKEFILE (all caps)

Answer (score -1):

i have write mistake the file name like MakeFile i also get the make: *** No rule to make target `gen'.  Stop. i find i mistake the file name i rename to Makefile and then i get okay.