# *** No rule to make target 'class.cpp', needed by `build/....x86/class.o` Stop. error in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, compilation, gnu-make

I got this error trying to build and compile my program. Now I can't open all my .cpp files in my program.

> make[2]: *** No rule to make target `Checker.cpp', needed by`
>   build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Checker.o'.  Stop.

Anyone can help me with this? I have checked all the online sources but I can't seem to find a solution. I desperately need this solved. Appreciate any help given.

Comment: It means that it can't find your source file Checker.cpp. Double check your paths.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834748/gcc-makefile-error-no-rule-to-make-target

Comment: Q: Are you sure you *HAVE* a file called "Checker.cpp"?  Is it in the correct directory?

Comment: Ok stupid mistake. The .cpp files were moved to another folder instead of copied when I did the transfer. Thanks guys. Anyone who post the answer I will select it ^^

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You get this error when you don't have a file (`Checker.cpp`) here to `make`. Its probably for the following reasons :

- Your current directory is not the directory in which your file
  resides.
- The file may have been moved to somewhere else.
- Or the worse , the file doesn't exist.