# make: *** No rule to make target ? `file.ext', needed by `mystepN'. Stop

Tags: makefile, topojson

I have a hand of commands which each works perfectly in the console when isolated. To ease my work, I collected them into a makefile:

```
topojsoning: levels.json
    topojson --id-property none -p name=elev -o final.json levels.json

geojsoning: contours.shp
    ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -where "elev < 10000" levels.json contours.shp

shaping: crop.tif
    gdal_contour -a elev -fl -1000 -500 -200 -50 0 50 100 200 500 1000 2000 4000 6000 crop.tif contours.shp

boxing: ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif
    gdal_translate -projwin -005.48 051.30 10.00 041.00 ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif crop.tif
    # ulx uly lrx lry  // W N E S // -005.48 051.30 10.00 041.00

unzip: ETOPO1.zip
    unzip ETOPO1.zip
    touch ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif

download:
    curl -o ETOPO1.zip 'http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/data/ice_surface/grid_registered/georeferenced_tiff/ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.zip'

clean:
    rm `ls | grep -v 'zip' | grep -v 'Makefile' `
```

Yet, when It is within my makefile, I get the following error :

```
make: *** No rule to make target ? `levels.json', needed by `topojsoning'.  Stop.
```

**What does this error means ? How to make it works ? Did I made a small typo ?**

Comment: Did you write this makefile? this is literally the most common error in makefiles, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834748/gcc-makefile-error-no-rule-to-make-target)

Comment: Does `levels.json` already exist?

Comment: I found my fix. I can't start each steps by a random title (process name), but should use the target file name. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the full fix:

```
# topojsoning: 
final.json: levels.json
    topojson --id-property none -p name=elev -o final.json levels.json

# geojsoning: 
levels.json: contours.shp
    ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -where "elev < 10000" levels.json contours.shp

# shaping: 
contours.shp: crop.tif
    gdal_contour -a elev -fl -1000 -500 -200 -50 0 50 100 200 500 1000 2000 4000 6000 crop.tif contours.shp

# boxing: 
crop.tif: ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif
    gdal_translate -projwin -005.48 051.30 10.00 041.00 ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif crop.tif
    # ulx uly lrx lry  // W N E S // -005.48 051.30 10.00 041.00

# unzip:
ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif: ETOPO1.zip
    unzip ETOPO1.zip
    touch ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif

# download:
ETOPO1.zip:
    curl -o ETOPO1.zip 'http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/data/ice_surface/grid_registered/georeferenced_tiff/ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.zip'

clean:
    rm `ls | grep -v 'zip' | grep -v 'Makefile' `
```

I was misusing the makefile syntaxe. I was starting each step by a **process name** (i.e. `topojsoning`, bad) :

```
processName: sourcefile
    command
```

should start with the **target file** (final.json, good):

```
targetfile: sourcefile
    command
```