# C++ Makefile Can't Find Files

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw

So I have run into an odd issue with makefiles using mingw's mingw32-make. I've scoured about and I'm clueless. It looks like this is a path issue where make is not looking into the correct folder, but I could be wrong..

I have configured it to run via nppexec so I am using this macro

```
mingw32-make.exe -f "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART)$(EXT_PART)"
```

Which gives..

```
mingw32-make.exe: *** No rule to make target 'main.cpp', needed by 'main.o'.  Stop.
```

makefile.mak (I know it dosen't need an extension)

```
CPP = g++.exe 
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

all: sortA4

sortA4: main.o Sortings.o
$(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -o sortA4 main.o Sortings.o

main.o: main.cpp Sortings.h
$(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c main.cpp

Sortings.o: Sortings.cpp Sortings.h
$(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c Sortings.cpp

#clean: >>>temp removed for debugging
#   $(RM) count *.o *~
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [gcc makefile error: "No rule to make target ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834748/gcc-makefile-error-no-rule-to-make-target)

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but you are sure that there is a main.cpp in the directory of the Makefile?

Comment: make looks for dependencies in the current directory. I don't know much about mingw, but I don't suppose it's much different. You probably need to be in the source directory for it to work.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834748/gcc-makefile-error-no-rule-to-make-target

Comment: @kfsone,risi I checked that.. Put it under C and nothing

Comment: @njansen, it exists there but yep still that error

Comment: Everything is where it should be.. All under one folder etc etc. I just triple check I mean is there an extra switch for stating where it should look

Comment: @user2859337 Do you have a clear understand of what "current directory" means? Hint: it is not the directory where the exe is.

Comment: What is the value of "CURRENT_DIRECTORY"? Is it the same as the location of main.cpp?

Comment: In this case cd is pointing to my files locations. Aka all the ones open, I am aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing this from the command line or visual studio? Did you set the working directory for the command to be "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"? If not, then it's trying to do this from the project/solution directory.

Comment: Command line, and the cd is set to look into the folder my files are in

Comment: Hold on you gave me an idea.. I might have failed to update this on my home pc. Maybe it isn't

Comment: If I were you, I'd put a pwd (pwd.exe?) line in your makefile as the first command to make main.o. That would almost certainly help you answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

All worked out.. I just forgot to change it because I set up the same thing on two computers and never updated where nppexec pointed. Stupid me for thinking it was fine..