# How to run makefile in Cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I am trying to run Makefile in cygwin.
Error msg:

```
$ make /cygdrive/d/IoT/trunk/Macchina/TestBed/Makefile
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `/cygdrive/d/IoT/trunk/Macchina/TestBed/Makefile'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not an image. It's impossible to read.

Comment: done,can you please check?

Comment: possible duplicate of [gcc makefile error: "No rule to make target ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834748/gcc-makefile-error-no-rule-to-make-target)

Answer (score 4):

You don't give make the makefile as an argument like that.

`cd` to that directory and run `make`.

Or *if* that makefile is intended to be used from other directories as well then you can try `make -f /cygdrive/d/IoT/trunk/Macchina/TestBed/Makefile`.