# how to add a c++ file in Qt Creator whose name starts with capital letters ? It automatically makes it small letter

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am trying to add a c++ file to a existing Qt project but I can't make the name  of the c++ file start with a capital letter. 
E.g. DownloadOsm.cpp becomes downloadosm.cpp automatically using the wizard.

Comment: You could probably add it to the appropriate `.pro` or `.pri` file manually.

Comment: You can build a Qt project manually, e.g. by having your own (small) `Makefile`

Answer (score 12):

To solve this issue do the following:

[Tools] -> [Options] -> [C++] -> [File Naming] -> uncheck "Lower case file names"

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed the case when you try to use the wizard to add new **C++ Source File** or **C++ Header File**. For those wizards - I could not find the way to make the names to follow the name convention you chose for your class name.

However, I found that when you use **C++ Class** wizard, it allows you to edit the names of header and source files. So, I try to only use the **C++ Class** wizard, it saves me time to rename just created files and is quite convenient for my purposes.

[image: Qt wizard new C++ class]

Answer (score -1):

I made a .cpp file which satisfy your conditions in the following way:

*Create .cpp file*

Open your Qt project directory and create a new .cpp file (DownloadOsm.cpp)

*Add to project*

Open your project (.pro) file in Qt Creator and right click on the *Sources* subfolder and select *Add Existing Files* from there choose your .cpp file (DownloadOsm.cpp)