# Running Makefile continuously gives `No rule to make target` error

Tags: makefile

I'm new to using makefiles for my projects, and I decided to start since I got tired of writing out all of the commands and arguments.

The current makefile that I have looks like this:

```
run_program:
        CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1
        python DIR/main.py --setup2
```

When I run this program using the following command:

```
make run_program
```

I get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'run_program'.  Stop
```

I've made sure that the makefile is in the appropriate directory and that there are no spelling errors of the sort, but I'm having trouble figuring out what I did wrong. I've checked others answers such as [gcc makefile error: “No rule to make target …”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834748/gcc-makefile-error-no-rule-to-make-target) but I'm not sure how to apply it to my case.

Any tips or advice are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How odd. What happens when you just `make`?

Comment: I receive the error message `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. What is the name of your makefile?

Comment: The name of my makefile is `make.mk`.

Comment: I have another makefile named `makefile.mk` and this doesn't work either. :(

Comment: I found the problem. Apparently I need to add the `-f` option and it runs. But... Why is this the case? Is this normal behavior for makefiles?

Comment: When you `make`, Make doesn't know which makefile you're thinking of. You can specify a makefile with `-f`, and if you don't, [Make will search for a couple of variants of "Makefile"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per 'make' info page:

> make executes commands in the makefile to update one or more target
>   names, where name is typically a program.  If no -f option is present,
>   make will look  for
>          the makefiles GNUmakefile, makefile, and Makefile, in that order.

If you name your makefile in other name, you will have to use the '-f'. While this is a good practice to name makefiles with '.mk' suffix (e.g., makefile for sub projects), most projects will name the "main" makefile to match on the the defaults, usually 'Makefile'.