# make: *** No rule to make target 'generic64/libkeccak.a'

Tags: c++, keccak, post-quantum-cryptography

I downloaded some post quantum algorithms from NIST and tested them. Some codes need to use Keccak package, so I downloaded it. When I tried to "make generic64/libkeccak.a", I got an error message:

*make: *** No rule to make target 'generic64/libkeccak.a'. Stop.*

How can I fix it? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Hi @andycc1126 and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting your questions, as a good quality question will help you attract good quality answers!

Comment: Why are you trying to make the library if it's already installed? Do you mean you downloaded the source and want to build it? Or is the library already built and installed?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain clearly. Yes, I downloaded the keccak pakage and want to build it. I got an error when building the required static library.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment due to less reputation.

This maybe because:

1. There is no Makefile in current working directory
2. The Makefile doesn't have any specific rule related to your request.

If you run `make blablablaSomeRandomThing`, you'll get the same error.
Maybe try running `make`, or better will be to open Makefile and see the present rules.

You may want to explore more on Makefiles:

https://opensource.com/article/18/8/what-how-makefile
https://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

Similar questions:

[gcc makefile error: "No rule to make target ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834748/gcc-makefile-error-no-rule-to-make-target)

Comment: Thank you for your advice!!  I will try modifying the Makefile later.