# "No rule to make target" when compiling glib

Tags: makefile

I am currently trying to build a software. However during its compilation, it stops with the following error messages:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h', needed by `GLib-2.0.gir'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/gobject-introspection-1.30.0'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/gobject-introspection-1.30.0'
```

make: *** [all] Error 2
...

I read a thread about a similar error message here: [gcc makefile error: "No rule to make target ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834748/gcc-makefile-error-no-rule-to-make-target) however, I was not able to use it on my case. All I can say is that the dir where glibconfig.h is found, shows here:

```
$(GLIB_LIBDIR)/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h
```

I guess I have to edit the Makefile and add something, but what? Not sure what .gir files are

Comment: This looks like make variable GLIB_LIBDIR is empty for some reason, which it shouldn't. Can it be set, e.g., with a `configure` option?

Comment: The configure's help does not mention it. Using grep on the Makefile, it returns: GLIB_LIBDIR = $(shell pkg-config --variable=libdir glib-2.0)
            -I$(GLIB_LIBDIR)/glib-2.0/include \
                $(GLIB_LIBDIR)/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h